# Error with Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Sorry my bad English.

I have the following "activity_main.xml" file, the problem is that the Toolbar NOT appears, someone tells me how to make her look?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/anchor_point"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:elevation="4dp"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

with this other "activity_main.xml" Toolbar appears, but lacks the Navigation Drawer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    /android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try adding this line in navigationview in your activity_main xml 'android:layout_below = "@+id/toolbar" ' .. let me know further..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it will work

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Real content goes here -->
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/navigation"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```